# list of dictionaries from single dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary like this

```
dict1 = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

how do I have an array of the keys and values as dictionaries like this

```
array_of_dict_values = [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}]
```

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're able to do so you might consider using a list of tuples `(key, value)` which can be re-converted in a dictionary directly if needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> aDict = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> aList = [{k:v} for k, v in aDict.items()]
>>> aList
[{'key2': 'value2'}, {'key1': 'value1'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

While somebody already answered with how to do this, I'm going to answer with "you probably don't want to do this." If every entry is a dictionary with a single key, wouldn't a list of key-value pairs work just as well?

```
dictionary = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
print(list(dictionary.items()))
# [('key2', 'value2'), ('key1', 'value1')]
```